# Formatting print from itertools permutations

Tags: python, printing, format, python-itertools

I picked up from an old post here that it is not possible to print the results of an itertools.permutations except by converting to a list first. This is what I did here:

```
import itertools

p = itertools.permutations('ABCD', 2)

print(list(p))
```

I get the following output (in Jupyter Notebook):

[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')]

I picked up the original example from [itertools from docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#). The example section on that page shows the output as:

AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC

That same page doesn't actually explain how to use itertools, having to import the module or how to get the output, so do I take it also that although it shows that output in a conveniently readable format, it was not produced in code but just typeset this way?

Either way, is there a way to tweak that print command to produce the same format as above?

Thank you for your comments and suggestions.

All the best. c

Comment: `' '.join(''.join(t) for t in p)`

Comment: (Note - try the above _without_ first doing `print(list(p))` or it won't work - you can only iterate over the iterator once.)

Comment: "I picked up the original example from itertools from docs.python.org." The code shown there is **not** an example - it's an *illustration* of what the library function does. The comments there do **not** show the *exact* output; they just give the general idea of what each output item contains. "That same page doesn't actually explain how to use itertools" - sure it does; what you want to do goes beyond simply "using itertools" into actually seeing the results. "having to import the module" - well, yes; of course you can't use a module without importing it; what did you expect?

Comment: The library documentation expects you to know some fundamentals about the language, but you *can* learn some more useful things from the ["language reference" section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html), as well as the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Karl Knechtel Karl, yes, that's what I thought when I wrote it was just conveniently typeset. But regarding importing a module, I meant to say there are no code snippets starting with import and showing a waltkhrough. A bit disconcerting for a newbie like me. I'm sure you're a seasoned developer, but I had to use another site just to get a complete picture of the syntax. Just saw your second post: thank you for the additional links. Will read and learn.
  

alaniwi Thank you. Will try and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
import itertools

p = itertools.permutations('ABCD', 2)

print(' '.join([a+b for a,b in p]))
```

Output:

```
AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Next(p)` to iterate through iterable objects 
or :

```
# import itertools

p = itertools.permutations('ABCD', 2)
for i in p:
    print("".join(i), end=" ")
```